# javascript convert timestamp different from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
var h = new Date(timestamp*1000).getHours();

date('H', $timestamp)
```

when I try to convert timestamp from javascript, i got different value from php

how can I get the same value from PHP?

```
ex. 28800, java-> 19, php->00
```

Comment: JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds. PHP's are not.

Comment: i did times 1000 already

Comment: He means divide by 1000, not multiply

Comment: Javascript pulls the time of your local computer, php pulls the time of the server. They just don't match.

Comment: @Machavity If you read the code he is turning a php timestamp into a javascript timestamp by multiplying by 1000.

Comment: Could it be the timezone of your server vs the timezone of local machine?

Comment: i need js follow my server's time, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to assign the time into a javascript variable.

In your Javascript:

```
var server_time = '<?php print date("Y-m-d"); ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and this was the exact situation I was facing  all day along.

First the JS time stamps are in milliseconds and PHP are not.

I was sending JS timestamps to PHP and trying to convert that to PHP date and all was going wrong.

So this is what I have done to resolve the issue

```
$jts = 1392143400000 ; // timestamp received from JS via ajax
$ts = $jts/1000
$date = date("Y-m-d",$ts);
```

So the dates got matched.

Now problem 2

- Server is in EST time zone and when any specific date is sent from my time zone say IST the above also does not work.

Thankfully my app requires user timezone to be stored in DB at the time of registration I solved this mismatch as

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$ts = 1392143400000/1000 ;
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); // Get the timezone from user id.
$dt->setTimestamp($ts);
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```